# Excessive white space appear out of nowhere, disappear when I use developer mode F12

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress site https://nasavape.com/, installed theme, woocommerce and some standard plugin.

After some content updates, there is some long vertical white space appear in the product grid element, which shows the recent product from woocommerce.
[image: Large white spaces]

These white spaces disappear when I tried to inspect in chrome dev mode.

[image: white spaces disappeared]

The above image is how it should look.

I have check everywhere and I can't seem to find the solution..

Hope someone might have a clue what's wrong.

I have tried deleteing the product grid and the problem still exist, i have also disabled minify CSS, JS, html.

I am expecting no large white spaces under the product grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JS script that is adding custom height dynamically. You can use this CSS to fix the issue.

```css
.woocommerce div.product.columns.dfd-loop-shop-responsive {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 1px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Sir!!! been looking at this problem for ages !! you are a life saver